# PyQt4 character encoding: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, character-encoding, pyqt4

Trying to use this following script to load a page so that I can access the page with javascript executed. I would like to log in and look at the resultant page (https://www.thomsononeim.com/v-hom.asp), also with Javascript executed. In Python 2.7, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Python27/Sample
>   Programs/Stupid Test.py", line 22, in
>   
>       print html UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
>   u'\xa9' in position 8273: ordinal not
>   in range(128)

Here's the code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = 'https://www.thomsononeim.com/s-log_in.asp'
r = Render(url)
html = r.frame.toHtml()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
print(html.toUtf8())
```